# Find object within array of arrays and return the array it belongs to

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array structure:

```
const array = [array1, array2, array3];
```

Each one of the three arrays consists of objects of form:

```
array1 = [{x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 5, y: 9}, {x: 1, y: 8}, {x: 3, y: 2}, etc]
```

I am trying to find the most efficient way to go through arrays of array and return the array to which a particular (unique) object belongs. For example I have object

> `{x:9, y:5}`

which can be uniquely found in array2, so I want to return array2.

here's what I've tried:

```
const array = [array1, array2, array3];
for (let x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++) {
    array[x].find(e => e === array[x][y])
    return array[x];
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the wording "sort through" is misleading. Anyways, what's wrong with two for loops, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Two loops one nested in the other is 100% necessary. It doesn't have to be a for loop, but you need two iterative processes, one nested in the other, to achieve what you want with any sort of consistency.

Comment: Is the object you look for the object *itself*, or an object that is a look-alike having the same properties?

Comment: I am only looking for the array which this object belongs to

Comment: That does not answer my question. Do you look for the same object reference, or can the object with which you search be a **new** object that just happens to have the same properties as one inside those arrays?

Comment: ah I see what you mean, same object reference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need two loops, but you can use methods that do the iteration for you:

```js
let array1 = [{x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 5, y: 9}, {x: 1, y: 8}, {x: 3, y: 2}];
let array2 = [{x: 5, y: 4}, {x: 4, y: 5}, {x: 8, y: 8}, {x: 3, y: 2}];
let array3 = [{x: 4, y: 3}, {x: 0, y: 6}, {x: 7, y: 8}, {x: 5, y: 2}];

const array = [array1, array2, array3];
let obj = array2[2];  // let's find this one...

let result = array.find(arr => arr.includes(obj));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here use `find`

```js
data = [
  [{x:1, y:2}, {x:2, y:3}],
  [{x:3, y:2}, {x:4, y:3}],
  [{x:5, y:2}, {x:6, y:3}],
  [{x:7, y:2}, {x:8, y:3}]
];

const getArray = ({x, y}) => data.find(a => a.some(o => o.x === x && o.y === y));

console.log(getArray({x:3, y:2}));
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; There is a working example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/to1kuazx/17/)

This can be accomplished using the following 3 things:

- a library such as `lodash` to check for object equality (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual)

  - The reason for this is that the behaviour of directly comparing two objects is different than you might think [more info here](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html)
- `array.findIndex` to find the index of the outer array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- `array.find` to find the element in an inner array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

The following method `findObjectInNestedArray` will do what you'd like.

```js
const findObjectArray = (obj, arr) => {
  index = arr.findIndex(a => a.find(e => _.isEqual(e, obj)))
  return arr[index] // will return `undefined` if not found
}

// Example code below

const array1 = [{x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 5, y: 9}, {x: 1, y: 8}, {x: 3, y: 2}];
const array2 = [{x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 3}, {x: 4, y: 4}, {x:9, y:5}];
const array3 = [{x: 5, y: 5}];

const arrays = [array1, array2, array3];

const inArray2 = {x:9, y:5};
const notInAnyArray = {x:0, y:0};

console.log('array2', findObjectArray(inArray2, arrays));
console.log('not in array', findObjectArray(notInAnyArray, arrays));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I said a single iteration was impossible before, but I devised a possible method that could work under specific circumstances. Essentially, you can sort the properties then stringify the objects for instant lookups. The sort is necessary to ensure you always get a consistent stringified output regardless of the object's properties preexisting order. There are three caveats to this method:

1. the objects CANNOT contain functions. Properties with functions are dropped in the stringification process.
2. NaN and infinity are converted to null, which can cause unexpected "matches" in the cache
3. If the depth of the object is not known (i.e. the target objects can contain references to arrays and other objects), then you'll need to deeply traverse through every level before stringifying.

It's a trade-off that's only improves performance when comparing deeply nested or extremely large objects. It's scalable, though, I guess.. Here's an example of how it could be done:

```js
// sort's an array's values, handling subarrays and objects with recursion
const sortArr = arr => arr.sort().map(el => typeof el === 'object' ? (Array.isArray(el) ? sortArr(el) : sortObj(el)) : el)

// sorts a key's objects, then recreates the object in a consistent order
const sortObj = obj => Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce((final, prop) => {
  final[prop] = (
    // if it's an object, we'll need to sort that...
    typeof obj[prop] === 'object'
    ? (
      Array.isArray(obj[prop])
        ? sortArr(obj[prop])//<-- recursively sort subarray
        : sortObj(obj[prop])//<-- recursively sort subobject
    )
    // otherwise, just retrun the value
    : obj[prop]
  )
  return final
}, {})

// for every element in the given array, deeply sort then stringify it
const deepSortObjectArray = (arr) => arr.map(el => JSON.stringify(sortObj(el)))

// from those strings, create an object with the strings as values and an associated 'true' boolean
const obejctCache = (obj) => deepSortObjectArray(obj).reduce((acc, el) => ({[el]: true, ...acc}), {})

// create an object string cache for every object in the array: 
const cacheObjectArrays = arr => arr.map(obj => obejctCache(obj))

// perform an O(1) lookup in each of the caches for a matching value: 
const findArrayContainer = (obj, caches) => {
  const stringLookupObj = JSON.stringify(sortObj(obj))
  return caches.findIndex(cache => cache[stringLookupObj])
}

const array = [
  {y: 1, x: 0}, 
  {x: 5, y: 9}, 
  {x: 1, y: 8}, 
  {x: 3, y: {z: 3, x: 1, y: 2}}
]
const arrayArray = [[], [], array]
const cachesArrays = cacheObjectArrays(arrayArray)
console.log(cachesArrays)
/* output: [ 
  {}, 
  {}, 
  { '{"x":3,"y":{"x":1,"y":2,"z":3}}': true,'{"x":1, "y":8}': true, '{"x":5,"y":9}': true,'{"x":0,"y":1}': true } 
]
*/

console.log(findArrayContainer({y: 1, x: 0}, cachesArrays))
// output: 2; working normally!
console.log(findArrayContainer({x: 0, y: 1}, cachesArrays))
// output: 2; working regardless of order!
console.log(findArrayContainer({y: 1, x: 0, q: 0}, cachesArrays))
// output: -1; working as expected with non-found objects!
```

As you can see, it's pretty complicated. Unless you're 100% this is actually the performance bottleneck, these performance gains may not translate to making interaction smoother.

Let me know if you have any questions about it!